# If a question is a subset of a current question, is it a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140083/played-convinced-sorcerer-warlock-can-make-infinite-spell-slots-with-short-rest) just came up and I had marked it as a duplicate. However, the comment thread has brought it to a point that I'm not sure it still is or how to handle it or similar questions.

It's clear that the question is 100% contained in the [currently linked duplicate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78918/does-this-character-concept-involving-never-taking-a-long-rest-and-converting-sp), but the answers also don't satisfy the current querent about the specific concern of generating more than the existing spell slots.

Should we clarify the new question to only be about the specific concern and link the older question as relevant, or is this more about getting a better answer to the older?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Make it a general question about Flexible Casting

If you remove the reference to the "coffelock" build, this question is in no way a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! I understood the general guidelines but the fact that it was about a coffeelock made me second guess and why i made the meta. Glad you got the answer in before it was duped.